# Access a serializer via a variable in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In the create method in my serializer I'm trying to send a portion of validated data to another serializer as below:

`new_serializer = NewSerializer(validated_data.get('customer'))` 
`new_serializer.save()`

But in the place of NewSerializer I want to be able to use a variable. I have a dictionary where each model is mapped to its serializer.

`my_dict = {"Model1": "Serializer1", "Model2": "Serializer2"}`

The model name is available to me and I will use that to find out the corresponding serializer from the dictionary. I have over fifty serializers and I may have to use any one so importing all of them will not be feasible.  I want to do something like this:

`the_serializer = mydict.get('Model1')`
`new_serializer = the_serializer(validated_data.get('customer'))`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by using import_string in django. I had my app_name and model_name present which were used to import the serializer. All of my serializers are named in {model_name}Serializer format so this way worked for me.

`serializer_name = import_string(f"{app_name}.serializers {model_name}Serializer")` 
`ins = serializer_name(data = main_data)`
`if ins.is_valid():` 
    `ins.save()`

Here's the django documentation link.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/?fbclid=IwAR22qaDgk0xT9nOY0lP4s3tVh2aKEleefFWQf_L6th5I0DQ56RUMpUmskpo#module-django.utils.module_loading

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I interpreted that you want to instantiate a class where the classname is provided by a variable.

For doing so, you can use `getattr`, however, you need to know in which module the class to be instantiated is located.

For instance, if your serializer class is defined in a module `foo.py`, you can do something like:

```
import foo
from yourapp.serializers import DefaultSerializer

the_serializer = "NewSerializer"
SerializerClass = getattr(foo, the_serializer, DefaultSerializer)
args = ("args", "to", "your", "serializer")
serializer_object = SerializerClass(*args)
```

Or in case you need to handle erronous serializer names:

```
try:
    SerializerClass = getattr(foo, the_serializer, DefaultSerializer)
    args = ("args", "to", "your", "serializer")
    serializer_object = SerializerClass(*args)
except AttributeError as ae:
    print(f"{ae}")
    # handle exception here
```

However, this approach of instantiating the class name doesn't appear appealing to me. There has to be some better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, importing the serializer will not be feasible for my application. I have updated the question to be a bit clearer. Please take a look.